# Arranging in ascending order in text file

Tags: python-3.x

So i have a text file which looks like this:

```
07,12,9201
07,12,9201
06,18,9209
06,18,9209
06,19,9209
06,19,9209
07,11,9201
```

I first want to remove all the duplicate lines, then sort column 1 in ascending order and then sort column 2 in ascending order given column 1 is still in ascending order.
output:

```
06,18,9209
06,19,9209
07,11,9201
07,12,9201
```

I have tried this so far:

```
with open('abc.txt') as f:
lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f]
```

Consider another example:

```
00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
00,6,6094
00,7,6094
00,8,6094
00,9,6498
00,2,6098
00,20,6102
00,21,6087
00,22,6087
00,23,6087
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
00,6,6094
00,7,6094
00,8,6094
00,9,6498
```

The output for this file should be:

```
00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,2,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
00,6,6094
00,7,6094
00,8,6094
00,9,6498
00,20,6102
00,21,6087
00,22,6087
00,23,6087
```

Comment: Please show your effort (code).

Comment: The source does not contain these lines ```00,10,6498
00,11,6498
00,12,6097
00,13,6097
00,14,6097
00,15,6097
00,16,6102
00,17,6102
00,18,6102
00,19,6102``` But the output does. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from collections import OrderedDict

input_file = 'input_file.txt'

# Collecting lines
lines = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in open(input_file)]

# Removing dups and Sorting by first column
sorted_lines = sorted(set(lines), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

# Grouping and ordering by second column
result = OrderedDict()
for k, g in groupby(sorted_lines, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    result[k] = sorted(g, key = lambda x : int(x[1]))

print(result)
for v in chain(*result.values()):
    print(','.join(v))
```

Output 1:

```
06,18,9209
06,19,9209
07,11,9201
07,12,9201
```

Output 2:

```
00,0,6098
00,1,6098
00,2,6098
00,3,6098
00,4,6094
00,5,6094
00,6,6094
00,7,6094
00,8,6094
00,9,6498
00,20,6102
00,21,6087
00,22,6087
00,23,6087
```

Comment: I added the case this code fails at in the question

Comment: @ksammy926 I have fixed it. Please check my latest edit. Fix is, that the values must be treated as int for sorting.